# Price Template addPriceBlockType on Related and Upsell Items

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, layout, price, template

I was able to successfully create a new template for price in product listing as well as in product page using this:

```
<reference name='product_list'>
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>simple</type>
                <block>catalog/product_price</block>
                <template>catalog/product/reseller/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
```

However, I could not do it in upsell or in related products block:

```
<reference name='catalog.product.related'>
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>simple</type>
                <block>catalog/product_price</block>
                <template>catalog/product/reseller/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
```

The rendered template is still using the old price template.
How can I possibly change price template in these blocks?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you do this in the layout local.xml or in a specific layout file?

Comment: Both. But it should work though especially if you add it in the catalog.xml file itself for testing.

Answer (score 3):

This is my wild guess. Not sure whether it works or not. However it feels logical to me. First of all you are using `addPriceBlockType()` function, which is defined in     `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` block class. Let us look what this method does.

```
public function addPriceBlockType($type, $block = '', $template = '')
    {
        if ($type) {
            $this->_priceBlockTypes[$type] = array(
                'block' => $block,
                'template' => $template
            );
        }
}
```

This method simply set `_priceBlockTypes` property with the given details. In our case, this property holds a values like this.

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::$_priceBlockTypes = array(
    'simple' => array(
        'block' => 'catalog/product_price',
        'template' => 'catalog/product/reseller/price.phtml'
    )
);
```

Layout job is over. Value is set correctly in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::$_priceBlockTypes`. Now we need to see how price template get rendering in frontend. For this take a look on `list.phtml`. You can see a code like this.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

In `related.phtml`, this block is invoked like this.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
```

Now it is important to know what `getPriceHtml()` does. Again this is a property of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` block class. Let us have a look.

```
public function getPriceHtml($product, $displayMinimalPrice = false, $idSuffix = '')
{
    $type_id = $product->getTypeId();
    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($product)) {
        $realPriceHtml = $this->_preparePriceRenderer($type_id)
            ->setProduct($product)
            ->setDisplayMinimalPrice($displayMinimalPrice)
            ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix)
            ->toHtml();
        $product->setAddToCartUrl($this->getAddToCartUrl($product));
        $product->setRealPriceHtml($realPriceHtml);
        $type_id = $this->_mapRenderer;
    }

    return $this->_preparePriceRenderer($type_id)
        ->setProduct($product)
        ->setDisplayMinimalPrice($displayMinimalPrice)
        ->setIdSuffix($idSuffix)
        ->toHtml();
}
```

A close look reveals that, the method first retrieves product's type id and then use that value to prepare price section. ie

```
$type_id = $product->getTypeId();
.....
return $this->_preparePriceRenderer($type_id);
```

Now let us have a look what this protected `_preparePriceRenderer()` method does.

```
public function _preparePriceRenderer($productType)
{
    return $this->_getPriceBlock($productType)
        ->setTemplate($this->_getPriceBlockTemplate($productType))
        ->setUseLinkForAsLowAs($this->_useLinkForAsLowAs);
}
```

This method gets the block according to the type id that passed and set a template to that block and returns it. If we didn't set a custom block for price block, `$this->_getPriceBlock($productType)` will use default block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price`. In our case, this default block is using. Now this block is setting with a template using the method `_getPriceBlockTemplate()`. Now let us have a look on that method.

```
protected function _getPriceBlockTemplate($productTypeId)
{
    if (isset($this->_priceBlockTypes[$productTypeId])) {
        if ($this->_priceBlockTypes[$productTypeId]['template'] != '') {
            return $this->_priceBlockTypes[$productTypeId]['template'];
        }
    }
    return $this->_priceBlockDefaultTemplate;
}
```

As you can see it returns a template, if a template is set based on the type. Else it uses default template `catalog/product/price.phtml`.

This is the theory. Now let us think what is the problem exists here. We have template only for `simple` product type. Related products may be of any type. It may be simple, bundle, configurable etc. In the current situation, it uses your custom template only for simple related products. Not for any other types. So you need to set your custom template for every other product types

**[edit]**

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name='catalog.product.related'>
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>simple</type>
                <block>catalog/product_price</block>
                <template>catalog/product/reseller/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>catalog/product_price</block>
                <template>catalog/product/reseller/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <!-- continue this for every type -->
    </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Hope that make sense !

### edit 2

It is wierd that, this method doesn't work. However there is an alternative solution for this. If you are no longer going to use the default price template, you can rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` block class and change the default template. However there is another problem. We cannot rewrite this class because it is an abstract class. So the easiest way to overwrite the method is "recreate" the same class in local pool.

File : `app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php`

```
<?php
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    /**
     * Rewrite constructor
     *
     */ 
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //set template using the method
        $this->addPriceBlockType('simple', 'catalog/product_price', 'catalog/product/reseller/price.phtml')

        //if the above method didn't work, use this along with that
        //sets your own template directly
        $this->__priceBlockDefaultTemplate = 'catalog/product/reseller/price.phtml';
    }

}
```

I have provided two ways to put your own custom price template. Use the last line, if the first condition fails again. If you are using the code, then you dont need to do any layout updates in anywhere. It will automatically use your custom price template every where it is displaying

Comment: Thank you @programmer_rkt for that clear explanation. On the last part though, the problem itself. Given that all my products are 'simple', How come it doesn't render the newly defined template?

Comment: where did you put this code? which layout file ?

Comment: catalog.xml in reference to catalog.product.related. Works fine using the references "product_list" and "product.info"

Comment: you need to put this code in `local.xml` file rather than `catalog.xml`

Comment: see my edit. If you have only simple product, only use that code for simple product

Comment: Sorry my comment was a bit unclear. I was referring to catalog.xml extending main catalog.xml, works similar with local.xml (EE1.14). Unfortunately, it didn't do the trick, tested on different XML files.

Comment: see my edit 2. It will solve your problem

Comment: It's not possible to rewrite abstract classes because their child classes literally extend them and they are never instantiated by Magentos factory methods

Comment: @fschmengler: Thanks for pointing out that mistake.. Be honest, at the time of answering, I was unaware of that point. Now I am. I appreciate your effort. More power to you :-)